# Why "$2n + 1 = (2n - 1) + 2$" leads one to conclude that "If $P_n$ is true then $P_{n+1}$ is also"

Tags: real-analysis

> Quoting: Example 1.2.4 Let $P_n$ be the proposition that $2n - 1$ is divisible by 2.
>
> **[argument 1]** If $P_n$ is true then $P_{n+1}$ is also, since
>   $2n + 1 = (2n - 1) + 2$
>
> **[argument 2]** However, we cannot conclude that $P_n$ is true for $n \geq 1$. In fact, $P_n$ is false for every $n$.
>   $\blacksquare$

I am new to this, reading this example on "mathematical Induction"

I am understanidng that " $2n + 1 = (2n - 1) + 2$", But, I am not understanding how it justifies that "If $P_n$ is true then $P_{n+1}$ is also"

The book does not elaborate more than this. Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: This example is probably just to show that both parts of a mathematical induction proof must be completed for the proof to be valid. The falsity that $2n-1$ is divisible by $2$, as shown, would be true if it was true for any $n\in \Re$, but it isn't, so that cannot be proven.

Comment: Since $2n-1$ is even and $2$ is even so is their sum $(2n-1)+2=2n+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $2n-1$ is divisible by $2$ (which it isn't but we are supposing that it is).  So that means $2n-1 = 2*k$ for some integer $k$.

$2n + 1 = (2n-1) + 2 = 2*k + 2 = 2(k+1)$.  So $2n+1$ is *also* divisible by $2$.

So *if* $2n-1$ is divisible by $2$ (which it isn't), it would logically follow that $2n+1 = (2n-1) + 2$ is as well (but it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that ***if*** $2n-1$ were divisible by $2$, then $2n+1$ would also be, because $2n +1=(2n-1)+2$ would mean $2n+1$ can be written as the sum of two terms each of which is divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$P_n$ says that $2n-1$ is divisible by $2$ and $P_{n+1}$ says that $2(n+1)-1$ is divisible by $2$. And if we assume ($P_n$) that $2n-1$ divisible by $2$, so is $2(n+1)-1 = 2n+1$ because $2n-1$ is divisible by $2$ means that there is a $k$ such that $2k = 2n-1$ and then $2k+2=2(k+1)$.